# Average and groupby SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the average frequency grouped by column 2.
The data is as follows:

```
+++++++++++++
col1 | col2 
+++++++++++++
a1 | b 
a1 | b
a2 | b
a3 | c
a4 | c
a1 | c
```

I need the result to be

```
++++++++++++
col2 | col3
++++++++++++
b | 1.5
c | 1
```

For eg: 'b' was chosen by 2 distinct values in col1. For each value in col2, `count(col2)/distinct(count(col1))`, grouped by col2 is what i want to calculate.

Comment: so what does your full query look like. would u be so nice providing it :)

Comment: And what is stopping u from writing it?

Comment: select 
colB as B, 
count(colB)/(distinct count colA) as avg_freq
from table
group by colB

Comment: @KaushikNayak Can I use distinct and count together as I have mentioned? I get an error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
SELECT col2 ,
       Count(col1) / Count (DISTINCT col1) AS avg_freq
FROM   table1
GROUP  BY col2;  

col2    AVG_FREQ
b       1.5
c       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT col2, count(col2) / count(DISTINCT col1) AS Avg_Freq
FROM   table1 GROUP  BY col2
```